# TortoiseSVN focuses on search bar in show log after comparing files

Tags: tortoise-svn

I am using the "Show Log" functionality to view differences and I pick a file to show by pressing <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. The file shows up and the differences are viewed. Then I press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to return to the "Show Log" dialog. But the cursor is focused on the search bar on top of the window instead of the file picker at the bottom. This makes it hard to go through a revision and check multiple files.

I remember that this functionality was there, but I cannot find the options to change it.

[image]

Comment: I don't have that problem using version 1.8.25.  I'm also not using the default diff viewer.

Comment: I'm using 1.8.11.26392 with the default diff viewer.